# REACT - defaultChecked don't render check attribute on second load

Tags: radio-button, react-router, reactjs

I got my component who won't check the radio when i go to the /view/:id for the second time. I started in my list component with react-router at the index of the site, i click on the view button of an element, the radio is checked, i return in my list and go to another or the same element and it's not checked anymore. When i inspect the component in the React developer tool, the radio has the defaultChecked=true property.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class LicenseRadios extends React.Component {
  buildRadios() {
    let { licenses, activeValue } = this.props;

    return licenses.map(license => {
      let checked = false;

      if(activeValue !== undefined && activeValue === license.id){
        checked = true;
      }

      return (
        <div key={license.id} className="col l2">
          <p>
            <input name="license" type="radio" id={'licenseRdo_' + license.id} value={license.id} defaultChecked={checked} />
            <label htmlFor={'licenseRdo_' + license.id}>{license.label}</label>
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        {this.buildRadios()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default LicenseRadios;
```

I tried to change the `defaultChecked` for the `checked` attribute, but it require an onChange event. I don't understand this problem. Can anybody help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `defaultChecked` prop is only used during initial render. If you need to update the value in a subsequent render, you will need to use an `onChange` function to handle value changes.

Check out [controlled components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) in the docs to better understand the problem you're having.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to pre-check a radio in the event that the component is re-rendered. An `onChange` action would not be triggered in this situation

Comment: I think one way to achieve this is to use a key for the component that holds the radio buttons and modify the key when the defaultChecked needs to change. If re-mounting the radio buttons is acceptable (since changing the key will force React to unmount the old ones and mount new ones), this should do it.

Answer (score 5):

use "undefined" for initial value for `defaultChecked` and re-render by setting it to `true` or `false`

```js
const Example = () => {

  [checked,setChecked] = useState(undefined);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
  
    // fetch data
    
    setChecked(true);
  
  });
  
  return (
    <input type="checkbox" defaultChecked={checked} onClick={(e)=> changeValue(e)}/>
  );

}
```